# angular 2 compiler/cli AoT in Rc5

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-rc5

currently i am using tsc compilet(JIT) to compile my angular 2 application. for performance improvisation i am trying to switch to Aot Compilation using compiler/Cli.

I am referring [this blog](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)  for AoT in my Rc5 Application.
but stuck due to error while installing

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save
```

[image: error]

I am confused between versions to use and proper direction.

Please suggest me blog or post for Aot in Angular 2 RC5 ?
or tell me what is version of angular/compiler-cli  to use for rc5
Help is really appreciated

Comment: May be you could take [this article](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html) as initial referece

Comment: thankyou @PankajParkar for reply. but i am facing issu when trying to install angular/compiler-cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question is off-topic and will result in mostly opinion based answers, I would suggest upgrading so that your application to the latest version of Angular. There is no reason to stay on a Release Candidate version.

After that install the [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and transfer your project.

You can then use `ng build --aot` to compile your project using Ahead of Time.

Comment: I cannot migrate to stable version for now. we are planning it in future.
But client in insisting on performance improvisation now. 

We have tried minification (html/js/css) and found that files are loading in about 2 seconds(max) but app is taking about 6 minutes to initilize

Comment: @sachinkulkarni with the latest angular, and using the cli to minify, optimize, treeshake, and ahead of time compile you code, your will see another huge improvement. 6 minutes initialisation is very doubtful coming from the angular side though. More probable this delay is coming from your database connection

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its 6 seconds

Comment: @sachinkulkarni then my advice sticks. For actual performance improvements. Upgrade your angular app, and use the angular-cli to build it